# Create users, groups and group_member using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following `csv` file :

```
first_name,last_name,department,job_title
Michael,Scott,TF_TEST1,Manager
Jim,Halpert,TF_TEST1,Engineer
Pam,Beesly,TF_TEST2,Engineer
```

I want to create all those users and set them member of the group corresponding to their departement, like :

| User | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Michael Scott | TF_TEST1 |
| Jim Halpert | TF_TEST1 |
| Pam Beesly | TF_TEST2 |

Here is what I have so far :

```hcl
# Configure the Azure Active Directory Provider
provider "azuread" {}

# Retrieve domain information
data "azuread_domains" "default" {
  only_initial = true
}

locals {
  domain_name = data.azuread_domains.default.domains.0.domain_name
  users       = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/users.csv"))
  groups      = toset(local.users[*].department)
}

resource "azuread_user" "users" {
  for_each = { for user in local.users : user.first_name => user }

  user_principal_name = format(
    "%s.%s@%s",
    lower(each.value.first_name),
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    local.domain_name
  )

  password = format(
    "%s%s%s!",
    lower(each.value.last_name),
    substr(lower(each.value.first_name), 0, 1),
    length(each.value.first_name)
  )
  force_password_change = true

  display_name = "${each.value.first_name} ${each.value.last_name}"
  department   = each.value.department
  job_title    = each.value.job_title
}

resource "azuread_group" "groups" {
  for_each     = local.groups
  display_name = each.key
  security_enabled   = true
  assignable_to_role = true
}
```

Users and groups get created just fine.
However I can't figure a way of adding those users inside their corresponding groups.

I feel like I should itarate through my `azuread_user.users` and `azuread_group.groups` to make the binding using a [group_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group_member) resources but no chance.
Or maybe that would be easier using the `members = []` property from [group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group) resource ?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: This is more like a thinking issue as I don't really know how I should undertake this problem

Comment: So the `members` argument should hold a list of users belonging to a group? In other words, you would like the users created using the resource to be added to the corresponding group?

Comment: That's exactly what I try to achieve indeed

Comment: How about `members = [  for user in values(azuread_user.users)[*] : user.department == each.key ? "ff43ab01-ce47-4e86-8583-e019ecd90819" : "aca87836-e78a-494d-b613-a6bfcff75996"]`?

Comment: I just realized that this portion of code shouldn't be present in my post. That was for testing purpose and didn't work out. I'll remove it as nothing should be hardcoded

Comment: Still I give a try to your answer and see if I can get something out of it !

Comment: Ok I'm almost there I think : `members = [ for u in values(azuread_user.users)[*] : u.department == each.key ? u.id : false]` The problm is the `ternary` operator requires me to set a else value, but in my case I just would like to skip to the next `for` iteration. Do you know how to solve this ? Here it will fails as it expected a valid `UID`, not a `false` value

Comment: You can use `u.id if u.department == each.key`. :)

Comment: Aaaahh finally ! It works just fine; cheers mate ;)
Please post your answer so I can upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Just a note that it works the same without the __[*]__  : `members = [ for u in values(azuread_user.users) : u.id if u.department == each.key ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion from the comments, you can achieve what you want by using a combination of `values` built-in function [1] and `if` instead of the ternary operator:

```
resource "azuread_group" "groups" {
  for_each           = local.groups
  display_name       = each.key
  security_enabled   = true
  assignable_to_role = true
  members = [ for u in values(azuread_user.users) : u.id if u.department == each.key ]
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values